# SQLalchemy + Flask: dynamic AND query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a m2m relationship for items and tags. I want to be able to create a dynamic AND query that would get every item that has every listed tag.

This is is a working example but I want to it to be dynamic(random amount of tags).

```
return Item.query.filter(Item.item_tag.any(name = 'test'))\
.filter(Item.item_tag.any(name = 'tag'))\
.filter(Item.item_tag.any(name = 'tag1'))\
.filter(Item.item_tag.any(name = 'tag2'))\
.all()
```

This is a working example for or_:

```
tags = or_( *[Tag.name==x for x in tags] )
return Item.query.join(Tag.items).filter(tags).all()
```

I'm looking for something similar for AND.

**Edit**: the generated sql for the working AND solution is:

```
SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.title AS item_title, item.url AS item_url, item.body AS item_body, item.itempic AS item_itempic, item.time_published AS item_time_published, item.private AS item_private, item.user_id AS item_user_id FROM item WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM item_tag, tag WHERE item.id = item_tag.item_id AND tag.id = item_tag.tag_id AND tag.name = ?)) AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM item_tag, tag WHERE item.id = item_tag.item_id AND tag.id = item_tag.tag_id AND tag.name = ?))
```

**Edit2:**

Example of what I need: Item1 has tags: tag1, tag2, tag3. Item2 has tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4.

When searching for the tags: tag1, tag2, tag3. Both item1 and item2 are returned. When searching for the tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4. Only item2 is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing the obvious, but:

```
tags = and_( *[Tag.name==x for x in tags] )
return Item.query.join(Tag.items).filter(tags).all()
```

Reference to this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_

Comment: When I use that query it tries to find a tag that has multiple names(I think).

This is the generated SQL for that query:


SELECT item.id AS item_id, item.title AS item_title, item.url AS item_url, item.body AS item_body, item.itempic AS item_itempic, item.time_published AS item_time_published, item.private AS item_private, item.user_id AS item_user_id FROM tag JOIN item_tag AS item_tag_1 ON tag.id = item_tag_1.tag_id JOIN item ON item.id = item_tag_1.item_id WHERE tag.name = ? AND tag.name = ?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure you phrased your question very clearly.

Why would you filter then iterate through any tags? Why not just have Item.query.all() (and if you need a random set, then use random module and .choice() to pick a number of returned-items)?

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something. Never had a need for this kind of query.

Comment: So should I query all the items and then do the search logic in the python code? I'll add an example to my original question to clarify this.